# URL title prefix - use slashes in prefix?

Tags: channel, url

EE3, Channel Settings.
It allows you to specify a URL prefix, i.e. to help the user fill in this field. Nice, i can start every URL with /book/ or /album/... Good for organisation and SEO love.

However, prefixes including slashes are seen as spaces, and spaces are not allowed. Error message: This field cannot contain spaces

Am i being a dummy, is there a good reason for this, or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't include forward slashes in the URL Title because EE breaks up every URL using `pathinfo`, and always treats the first two segments of the URL as template group/template. ([See docs on URL structure.](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/urls/url_structure.html))

If you want to organize your content into "types" via the URL for SEO purposes, I'd use template groups (or [template routes](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/urls/template_routes.html)) to achieve this instead.

Comment: Of course - i was thinking of Pages URL, and not URL_Title.